# Datenum hour intervals within days to plot with imagesc (Matlab)

Tags: plot, time, google-maps-markers

Good day,

I have an array UTTf in datenum format, which includes time markers for 10 days but only for [17:30-24] UTC.

I have the same size matrix cdgridN2f as time array and now I am trying to plot the data with imagesc.

However, instead of having time intervals of [17:30-24] UTC for each day, imagesc shows timestamps starting from the beginning of the day for all days except the first one (see figure).

My question is to how properly plot time ticks so it shows the data merged from many days, but for only specific interval of hours within each day.

Thanks in advance,

`imagesc(UTTf,lat,squeeze(cdgridN2f)) datetick`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLKCp.png)